# LateX output of Doxygen - order of chapters

Tags: latex, doxygen

I am trying to modify the order of chapters in the LaTeX output of Doxygen - analogous to the Layout file available for the html output, which allows the order to be customized. But for the LaTeX (refman.tex) output, I have not found a way.

I generated and modified DefaultLayout.xml, which only modifies the html Layout, but not the Latex Layout.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give an example, in the question, of the differences you made to your `DefaultLayout.xml` file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Doxygen 1.9.6. 
Changes to xml layout: Placed 'files' after 'pages'

Comment: <navindex>

    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="files" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="files" visible="yes" title=""/>
      <tab type="globals" visible="yes" title=""/>
    </tab>  
    <tab type="modules" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="yes" title=""/>
    </tab>

Comment: Apologies for the formatting of the example xml extract above. 
The changes result in a modified order of tabs the html layout. However, this has no effect in the Latex layout.